# Problem javascript function convert string value to int remove first zeros

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

Hello First value show in grid like this '001','002' when load data in grid . when i click edit button link value convert like this '1','2' so i don't want to remove 00 . 
in model column type is string and also in database string .

Grid Column Edit Button Link

```
{
                    name: 'CatCode', label: '', search: false, width: '40', frozen: true, formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject, rowdata) {
                        var rowID = rowObject['CatCode'];

                        if (rowID != null) {

                            return '<a href="javascript:ItemCatCodeGetby(' + rowID + ')" style="color: #3366ff" id=' + rowID + ' >Edit</a>';
                        }

                    }
                },
```

Javascript

```
function ItemCatCodeGetby(row) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("ItemCategory_Select")",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            data: { 'CatCode': row},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                $('#txtUCatCode').val(result.CatCode);
                $('#txtUCategoryDesc').val(result.CatDesc);
                $('#txtUHsCode').val(result.HS_Code);
                $('#txtUPurCode').val(result.PurCode);
                $('#txtUSaleCode').val(result.SaleCode);

                $('#txtUCostOfSaleCode').val(result.CostOfSaleCode);
                $('#txtUSaleCode_Trade').val(result.SaleCode_Trade);
                $('#txtUCostOfSaleCode_Trade').val(result.CostOfSaleCode_Trade);

                $('#ItemCUpdateModel').modal('show');
                $('#btnItemUpdate').show();
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: HTML Receive 1 but from database value getting 001 when edit button click then value change that is problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you're passing `001` to the function as a number and the preceding zeros are being automatically removed.

To prevent this you need to add quotes around the number, and to do that you need to escape them:

```
'<a href="javascript:ItemCatCodeGetby(\''+ rowid + '\')" style="color: #3366ff" id=' + rowID + ' >Edit</a>';
```

The alternative (and better long term option) is to remove the inline JS altogether and use classes, data attributes (and a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)), and attach event listeners to the buttons.

```
`<a class="edit" data-rowid="${rowid}" style="color: #3366ff">Edit</a>`;

const editButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.edit');
editButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', ItemCatCodeGetBy, false));

function ItemCatCodeGetBy() {
  // rowid is this.dataset.rowid
}
```